# How to stop Repeating characters at 2? REGEX

Tags: asp.net, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

`(\b(?:([A-Za-z0-9])(?!\2{2}))+\b)` actually does. but when a string like "pepper" comes, it doesnt hit. wen there are continuos 3 repeating characters, it hits. ?? Any clue?

Comment: unclear, what are you trying to achieve? post some examples for valid and invalid matches. or expected output.

Comment: maximum number of repeating characters should be 2. no matter where the repeation is happening.

Comment: should hit apppa. should hit papap. if the character exceeds 2 repeatations it should hit. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?=\S*(.)\S*\1)(?!\S*(\S)\S*\2\S*\2)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aG0sF5/5

Comment: maximum number of repeating characters should be 2. no matter where the repeation is happening.
     
should hit pappa, should hit apppa. should hit papap. if the character exceeds 2 repeatations it should hit. :( So confusing!

Comment: qwerty123 has no repeating characters, so no. it shudnt be hit. :)

Comment: one last doubt. its detecting repeated numbers too. its not needed. only repeated characters. how do i not check for numbers? i tried deleting the "0-9" part, but didnt help.

Comment: like this? " \b(?![a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*\1[a-zA-Z]*\1)[a-zA-Z]+\b"

Comment: @George `\b(?=\S*([a-zA-Z])\S*\1)(?!\S*([a-zA-Z])\S*\2\S*\2)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b` https://regex101.com/r/aG0sF5/6

Comment: The one you gave before was working fine. except with the number thing. but this one, not working at all.. sorry !!

Comment: @George check demo.it is working.have not changed much